# Удалить класс спустя какое то время

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
const runClass = elem => {
    !elem.classList.contains('class') && elem.classList.add('class');
    setTimeout(_ => elem.classList.remove('class'), 3000);
};

elem.onpointermove = e => runClass(e.target);
```

Когда пользователь наводит на элемент или по элементу мышей водит. Каждый раз вызываем класс, в нем необходимо добавить класс к элементу если его нет и удалить по истечению 3 секунд с момента последнего действия, то есть вызова.

В целом работает но криво. Удаляет класс по истечению 3 секунд и снова его добавляет. На некоторых элементах стоит анимация и когда класс добавляется по новой то и анимация тоже по новой. Как решить это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Анимация сбивается, судя по всему, из-за того, что `setTimeout` отрабатывает всегда, даже если последнее действие было совершено менее 3 секунд назад. Можно сбрасывать таймаут, чтобы класс не удалялся с элемента преждевременно:

```js
const elem = document.getElementById("box");
let timer = null;

const runClass = elem => {
  elem.classList.add('class');
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(() => elem.classList.remove('class'), 3000);
};

elem.onpointermove = e => runClass(e.target);
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы анимация не сбивалась, думаю нужны другие/дополнительные события элемента.

Вот это наводка: [События движения: "mouseover/out/move/leave/enter"](https://maxello.gitbooks.io/js-note/content/16_dom_events/sobitiya_dvizheniya_mouseoveroutmoveleaveenter.html)

Нужно запрограмировать событие входа/выхода в/из объект(а), введя булеву переменную состояния входа/выхода. Это основывается на событиях mouseover/mouseout и свойстве relatedTarget.

Событие mouseover происходит, когда мышь появляется над элементом, а mouseout — когда уходит из него. Требуется по логике оперировать этим дополнительным флагом.

```css
#box-id1 {
  width: 200px; height: 200px;
}
    
.box-red {
  background-color: red;  
}

.box-green {
  background-color: green;  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test mouse</title>
  <meta name="author" content="">
</head>



<body>
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-green" id="box-id1"></div>
</div>

<script>
  let box = document.querySelector("#box-id1");
  
  
  box.onmouseover = (event) => {
    box.classList.remove("box-green");
    box.classList.add("box-red");
  };
  
  box.onmouseout = (event) => {
    box.classList.remove("box-red");
    box.classList.add("box-green");
  };
  
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ссылка с ошибкой 401 :/

Comment: У меня она работает. Попробуйте перепроверить, только что зашел.

Comment: Заработала. Странно... Я пытался до этого перезайти...

Comment: Лучше оставьте ссылку на MDN или Javascript.INFO, они уж точно будут всегда работать.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать на jquery:

```js
$(".changeColor").mouseenter(() => {
  $(".changeColor").toggleClass("backgroundRed");
  $(".changeColor").toggleClass("backgroundGreen");
});
$(".changeColor").mouseout(() => {
  $(".changeColor").toggleClass("backgroundRed");
  $(".changeColor").toggleClass("backgroundGreen");
});
```

```css
.changeColor {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.backgroundRed {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.backgroundGreen {
  background-color: #00ff00
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<div class="changeColor backgroundRed"></div>
```

Comment: Нельзя :) Вопрос про JavaScript, там нет метки `jquery`